# Convert a Scheme constant to the equivalent Common Lisp

Tags: scheme, common-lisp

I am converting some Scheme code to Common Lisp. I don't know Scheme. I know a bit of Common Lisp.

I think this Scheme is defining a constant:

```
(define nothing #(*the-nothing*))
```

What is that `#` symbol doing? Why is it there?

I think this is the Common Lisp equivalent, but honestly I'm not sure:

```
(defconstant nothing '*the-nothing*)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both Scheme and Common Lisp, `#(...)` is read syntax for a vector. In this case, it's a vector containing 1 element, the symbol `*the-nothing*`.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Is it a common practice to create a constant using a vector? It seems simpler to use '*the-nothing*. Is there an advantage to using a vector to define a constant?

Comment: No, it's not common to see vectors used in this way. You'll have to look at the existing code to see why it used a vector. Maybe there's a valid reason.

Comment: This might be used as a way to get a new unique object for quick equality testing.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor is right here. The crucial point of nothing is that is an unique value. Use a Common Lisp construct that allocates in order to ensure uniqueness.